# Zabbix custom report development

Tags: zabbix

We are working on Zabbix custom report development, looking for guidance together historical data belongs to each item assigned to the host.

looking for historical data from each item mentioned in images
[image: looking for historical data from each item mentioned in images]

We are researching the historical data from the database, also we got the parent data from DB but didn't get child data for a history of each item history records with different timestamps.

Those all items are mentioned in the "ITEM" table, please help us to get the required data to generate the custom graphics. we wanted to design a custom report as per the below image.

looking for design graphics using historical data
[image: looking for design graphics using historical data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't access the database directly, use the [API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api) instead:

- [item.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/item/get): get informations about the item (type, query interval, key
  name and parameters)
- [history.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/history/get): get historycal data (full data on a
  specified interval)
- [trend.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/trend/get): get trend data (average/min/max data
  with a lesser granularity)

Each page has examples on how to interface to the api, [here](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/api/libraries) you can find some implementation for various languages.

[Here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/history_and_trends) you can find the exact difference between history and trend data.

Or you can use Grafana with the [Zabbix Plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app).

Comment: Really thanks for your kind words and help, we have tried to get data from the api but got some confusion,
1) we are trying to get data from history API but some of the items don't have data.
2) Trend api not working for us. getting below error 
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32700,
        "message": "Parse error",
        "data": "Invalid JSON. An error occurred on the server while parsing the JSON text."
    },
    "id": null
}

Kindly help me for the same. As we required to design graphics so we required data from trend api as well.

Comment: You should open two specific questions with your code and anything you tried, then the expected results.